# How can I undo `zg`?

Tags: spell-checking, undo-redo

I'm checking spelling in a document. I find a misspelled word and intend to press `z=` to get suggestions, but I accidentally press `zg`, marking this as a "good" spelling.

How can I undo that?

Comment: One way is to manually undo the changes to the spelling files and restart vim. But that's tedious.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the help

```
zuw                         *zug* *zuw*
zug         Undo |zw| and |zg|, remove the word from the entry in
            'spellfile'.  Count used as with |zg|.

zuW                         *zuG* *zuW*
zuG         Undo |zW| and |zG|, remove the word from the internal
            word list.  Count used as with |zg|.
```